# Exponential of the derivative operator on the Schwartz space?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

We consider the derivative operator $\mathrm{D}$ on the space of smooth and rapidly decreasing function $\mathcal{S}$. We denote by $P_n = \frac{1}{0!} + \frac{X}{1!} + \frac{X^2}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{X^n}{n!}$ and $\mathrm{T}_n = P_n(\mathrm{D})$.

My question is the following. Can we show that the sequence of operators $(\mathrm{T}_n)$ converges to some operator $\mathrm{T}$ from $\mathcal{S}$ to itself (that we could then call $\mathrm{T}= \exp(\mathrm{D})$)? If so, can we easily extend that operator over $\mathcal{S}'$?

I suspect, if the result is true, that we can prove it showing that the sequence $(\mathrm{T}_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in the complete topological vector space $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{S})$ of linear and continuous operator from $\mathcal{S}$ to $\mathcal{S}$. The topology of the space $\mathcal{S}$ is complete for the usual family of semi-norms $$\lVert f \lVert_{n,m} = \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}} | (1+|r|^m) D^{(n)} f(r) |.$$

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: As a first step, I would try to bound the rate of growth of 
$\| r^{\ell} f(r) \|_{m,n}$ as $\ell \rightarrow \infty$ for Schwartz functions $f$.  If your operators do converge, then the growth rate should be slower than $\ell!$.

Comment: For entire functions (not only those of rapid decay), $P_n(D)$ converges to a shift operator. Expand in a power series at 0 to verify.